# Sequelize complaining about unique primary key constraint but primary key is set to auto increment

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Hello i am experiencing a very strange problem, i searched a lot and didn't found any related results so i am preety much sure that this is not a duplicate.

Scenario
I am using Sequelize as a database ORM with PostGresql database engine. I wrote the following users schema

```
const User = sequelize.define("users", {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true
    },
    mobile: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },

});
```

and following array of records for bulk insert

```
const records = [
{
   name: 'ABC',
   email: 'test@domain.com',
   mobile: '123456789'
},
{
   name: 'IJK',
   email: 'mail@domain.com',
   mobile: '123456789'
},
{
   name: 'XYZ',
   email: 'yetanothermail@domain.com',
   mobile: '123456789'
}
];
const results = await User.bulkCreate(records, { updateOnDuplicate: [ 'email' ] });
```

Once the above statement is executed the sequelize gives the following error

> SequelizeUniqueConstraintError ERROR:  duplicate key value violates
> unique constraint "users_pkey" DETAIL:  Key (id)=(9) already exists.

But why it is so, when it is clear, it should be generated automatically (auto incremented) and in my records there is no id specified manually the error is not supposed to be raised.

Comment: Potentially your sequence is behind one of the values already inserted into the table somehow. You can try `PERFORM * FROM SETVAL('users_pkey', 10);` Or something greater than 9. Or to check what the sequence is currently holding: `SELECT * FROM LASTVAL('users_pkey');` I'm not sure about sequelize here but you should consider trying to use the `SERIAL` or `BIGSERIAL` datatypes instead of `INTEGER`

Comment: Wow, you saved my day, this solved the problem, i checked the last value was not the correct value, although my node is the only process inserting data but i will check what exactly caused this issue.